# Searching a std::vector for approximations of a value

Tags: c++, search, vector

I have a vector,

```
std::vector<float> v;
```

and a float value, **x**. The vector **v** contains **x+epsilon**, where **epsilon** is very small (yet greater than the machine epsilon), but it doesn't contain **x**. Is there a way, using the STL, to find the index of **x+epsilon** in the vector?

Something like:

```
int i = alternative_find(v.begin(), v.end(), x, gamma) - v.begin();
```

which will return the index of all the values in **v** which are in **[x-gamma,x+gamma]**? I could implement a binary search function (I'd like to avoid linear time complexity), but I'd really like to know if it could be done in an easier way.

Comment: What do you mean by returning all the values? Doesn't `std::find` find only the first?

Comment: @user2345215: Hence the question.

Comment: How big is tge vector, is it pre sorted for other reasons, do you care if the order changes, and how imoortant is performance?  Often sorting is not worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about binary search then obvious the `vector`'s pre-sorted, which means you want to find the first element above x-gamma, then if you actually want to use the values it's fastest to increment further while they're in range.  Check out `lower_bound`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound

If you just want to find the first and last, an alternative is to use `upper_bound` to binary search to its position, but that's likely slower than incrementing if there are a lot of elements and only a few match.

Answer (score 2):

**Find the `std::lower_bound`, then the `std::upper_bound`, and you'll have your range.**

From an iterator, you can obtain an index using `std::distance` (though stick with the iterator if you can!).

This assumes your data is sorted, but since you talk about binary searches that seems like a sensible assumption.

If it's *not* then you're going to have to examine every element anyway, in which case any approach is basically as good as another.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11:

```
std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
    [x,gamma](float f){return f >= x-gamma && f <= x+gamma;})
```

Historically, you'd have to write your own predicate, and it would probably be simpler to use a regular `for` loop.

(Although, regarding your last sentence, if the vector is or can be sorted, then you can do a binary search with `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` as described in other answers).

Comment: "index of all the values", "I could implement a binary search function (i'd like to avoid linear time complextiy"

Comment: @TonyD: Oh yes, I didn't notice that bit. If the array can be sorted, then there are already answers covering that.